# En una suma de números aparecen decimales en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

Estoy haciendo una página en la que seleccionas varios `input` con precios y te los suma para saber el precio total.

Uno es un `input` de tipo `number` que son los días, y multiplico el número por el precio que es decimal. Cada 2 días que añadas, se añade un decimal más que no sé de donde sale, no debería salir.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.miCheckbox');
  const precioTotal = document.querySelector('#total');
  var comedor = 0;
  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.id == 'hermano1' || this.id == 'hermano2' || this.id == 'hermano3') {
        total = total - (total * (parseFloat(this.dataset.price) / 100));
      } else if (this.id == 'serviciocomedor' || this.id == 'servicionocomedor') {
        total -= comedor;

        if ($('#serviciocomedor').val() >= 0 || $('#servicionocomedor').val() >= 0) {
          //Donde multiplico los días por el precio en decimal
          comedor = $('#serviciocomedor').val() * 4.40 - $('#servicionocomedor').val() * 8.50;
          total += parseFloat(comedor);
        }

      } else {
        if (this.checked) {
          total += parseFloat(this.dataset.price);
        } else {
          total -= parseFloat(this.dataset.price);
        }
      }
      precioTotal.innerHTML = `${total}€`;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 align="Justify">Servicio de catering</h3>
<p>
  <input type="number" class="miCheckbox" id="serviciocomedor" style="width: 40px;" /> Si ya se tiene servicio de comedor ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 4,40€/día
  <br>
  <input type="number" class="miCheckbox" id="servicionocomedor" style="width: 40px;" /> Si no tiene servicio de comedor -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 8,50€/día
  <br>
  <i>*Modificaciones para QUINCENAS (Sólo disponible en JULIO Y AGOSTO). Los meses de Julio y Agosto posibilidad de asistir por
                    quincenas.</i>
  <br><br>
</p>

<h3 align="Justify">Reducción de la cuota para varios hermanos</h3> (Comedor de dias sueltos y catering no tienen descuento)
<br>

<h2 align="Justify">Servicio de Conciliación</h2>
<p> <input type="checkbox" class="miCheckbox" id="horario5" data-price="90" /> Horario 7.30h a 16h ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 90€
  <br><br>
</p>
<div id="resultado"><b>Resultado: </b><span id="total">0€</span></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debería ser 13,2.

Comment: edita tu pregunta y adjunta también tu html para que sea reproducible tu código

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias.

Comment: La precisión de punto flotante es un problema muy común en JS, te recomiendo leer esta pregunta de SO.EN que tiene muchas recomendaciones de como lidiar con esa característica: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy empezando con JavaScript y no sabía sobre eso.

Answer (score 1):

Con [**`toFixed()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) defines a cuantos decimales quieres que esté el número, en tu caso, al **`toFixed()`** le doy como parámetro `1` ya que quiero solo un decimal, ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.miCheckbox');
  const precioTotal = document.querySelector('#total');
  var comedor = 0;
  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
      if (this.id == 'hermano1' || this.id == 'hermano2' || this.id == 'hermano3') {
        total = total - (total * (parseFloat(this.dataset.price) / 100));
      } else if (this.id == 'serviciocomedor' || this.id == 'servicionocomedor') {
        total -= comedor;

        if ($('#serviciocomedor').val() >= 0 || $('#servicionocomedor').val() >= 0) {
          //Donde multiplico los días por el precio en decimal
          comedor = $('#serviciocomedor').val() * 4.40 - $('#servicionocomedor').val() * 8.50;
          total += parseFloat(comedor);
        }

      } else {
        if (this.checked) {
          total += parseFloat(this.dataset.price);
        } else {
          total -= parseFloat(this.dataset.price);
        }
      }
      precioTotal.innerHTML = `${total.toFixed(1)}€`;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h3 align="Justify">Servicio de catering</h3>
<p>
  <input type="number" class="miCheckbox" id="serviciocomedor" style="width: 40px;"/> Si ya se tiene servicio de comedor ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 4,40€/día
  <br>
  <input type="number" class="miCheckbox" id="servicionocomedor" style="width: 40px;"/> Si no tiene servicio de comedor -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 8,50€/día
  <br>
  <i>*Modificaciones para QUINCENAS (Sólo disponible en JULIO Y AGOSTO). Los meses de Julio y Agosto posibilidad de asistir por quincenas.</i>
  <br><br>
</p>

<h3 align="Justify">Reducción de la cuota para varios hermanos</h3> (Comedor de dias sueltos y catering no tienen
descuento)
<br>

<h2 align="Justify">Servicio de Conciliación</h2>
<p> <input type="checkbox" class="miCheckbox" id="horario5" data-price="90"/> Horario 7.30h a 16h ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 90€
  <br><br>
</p>
<div id="resultado"><b>Resultado: </b><span id="total">0€</span></div>
```

Comment: Eso es una solución a corto plazo, es tapar el problema, pero saldrá por otro lado. Si luego quitas los días, internamente será un número negativo porque no contemplaba esos decimales de más. Así que esa solución no me sirve, gracias igualmente.

Comment: No entiendo, cuál sería el problema entonces?... los negativos ocurrían también sin el tofixed()... Entonces el problema sería otro (a parte de los decimales).

Comment: Pues que yo no necesito mostrar solo los que me interesa, yo necesito el número correcto porque hago más operaciones con ese número, hago restas y sumas. Si te fijas en la foto que he publicado da 13.2000000001, pero 3 x 4'4, es 13,2. No sé de donde sale el 00001 pero necesito que no me lo de o no me funciona bien.

Comment: Una posible solución sería algo como el toFixed(1), pero que se pudiese igualar a la variable. Para hacer algo como `total = total.toFixed(1)` pero eso no funciona. Igualmente, sigo sin entender porque 3 x 4,4 da un decimal, no le encuentro el sentido.

Comment: En los valores estás multiplicando por `4.40` y `8.50`, es por eso que te dan decimales... Y el `toFixed()` era para solucionar el problema que comentabas -> *se añade un decimal más que no sé de donde sale, debería ser 13,2*.